# Chrome OS not allowing connection from remote machine

Tags: networking, server, port, firewall, google-chrome-os

I have installed Chromebrew on chrome OS and running a server on port 8000. I am able to connect to the server locally but from remote machine the connection hangs and times out. I am not able to find any information if Chrome OS blocks ports for incoming connection. There is nothing in the Chrome OS setting to enable disable. Does Chrome OS blocks ports for incoming connection? Is it possible to change setting?

Comment: This type of question should be asked on [su].

Answer (score 0):

Turns out ports are inaccessible from outside on ChromeOS : ""android runs on a chromebook on a NAT interface that is not exposed directly on the LAN"[1]. Solution is to use [1]. Its also available on chrome webstore https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/connection-forwarder/ahaijnonphgkgnkbklchdhclailflinn.

[1] https://github.com/kzahel/connection-forwarder